# Fechar um modal BOOSTRAP e abrir outra em seguida?

Tags: bootstrap-3

1: Gostaria que, na minha modal de cadastro, ao clicar no link "Já possui conta? FAÇA LOGIN" a modal de cadastro se fechasse e abrisse a de login, já que o bootstrap não permite 2 modals abertas. Há algum comando pra fazer isso ? (img)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2: Ao clicar no botao "logar", há uma pesquisa no banco e, caso haja o usuario, aparece a div de configuração (dados, endereço, etc), porem a div de login continua aberta, o que fazer? (img2)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu usei a função "$("#login").modal('hide')", porem a modal sumiu, mas a tela continuou escura e o body desativado, como mostra a imagem: https://i.imgur.com/R80iTlL.png

Comment: utilizei a função "$("#login").modal('hide');" seguida de "$('.modal-backdrop').css('display', 'none');" e funcionou, porem a animação é muito lenta,

Comment: Olha, não teria que fechar a primeira e abrir a segunda em sequencia?

Comment: Vc quer que se clicar em "Fazer Login" dentro do modal "Faça seu Cadastro"  esse modal se feche? Não deu para entender direito...

Comment: Edward é o que estou tentando fazer

Comment: Hugo na primeira imagem eu disse que quando clicar em "ja possui conta? Faça login" fechasse a modal cadastro e abrisse a modal Login.

Na segunda imagem eu disse que após eu clicar em "Entre", gostaria que a div em questao se fechasse, porem ela continua aberta.

Answer (score 1):

Ao fechar a modal com `$("#login").modal('hide')`, use o callback do evento `hidden.bs.modal` para abrir a outra com `$("#cadastro").modal('show');`.

> Atente-se de que o Bootstrap 3 só funciona com jQuery a partir da
>   versão 1.9.1 e menor que 3.0.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$("#fazer_cadastro").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#login").modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      $("#cadastro").modal('show');
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="#" id="fazer_cadastro">Fazer cadastro</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="cadastro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cadastro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sam, primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda. Eu criei um html novo, um JS novo, so pra testar o seu código, e não funcionou, porém no seu exemplo está funcionando perfeitamente. Note: eu copiei exatamente o seu código, e a unica mudança foi inserir o meu javascript. Voce sabe qual pode ser o problema?